# ruby sorting two arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby: Sorting 2 arrays using values from one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002835/ruby-sorting-2-arrays-using-values-from-one-of-them)

I have an array that looks like this:

```
a = [[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]]
```

and an array `b` like this:

```
b = [5, 3, 4]
```

The elements in `b` correspond to the elements in `a` on the same index.  I want to sort `b`and at the same time the elements in `a` to change order in the same way as `b`.

So for the above example I would get:

```
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 1]] and b = [3, 4, 5]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002835/ruby-sorting-2-arrays-using-values-from-one-of-them) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]]
b = [5, 3, 4]
a, b = b.zip(a).sort.transpose
p b #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 1]]
```

To see how this works, just look at the result of `p  b.zip(a)`; then `p b.zip(a).transpose`.

Comment: I would prefer `sort_by(&:first)`

Comment: @VictorMoroz Or `sort_by(&:join)` to sort by all digits.

Comment: @RobertK: But what happens when you have things like `[11, 1]` and `[1, 11]`?

Comment: Ruby can sort by array, why bother using first ,last or even join? Just use `[[11,1],[1,11]].sort`, you will get `[[1, 11], [11, 1]]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick benchmark to show the outputs and execution times:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'pp'

a = [[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]]
b = [5, 3, 4]

pp a.sort_by.with_index{|_,i| b[i]}

a,b = b.zip(a).sort.transpose 
pp b

a = [[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]]
b = [5, 3, 4]
n = 1_000_000

puts "Using #{n} iterations:"
Benchmark.bm(7) do |bench|
  bench.report('sort_by') { n.times { a.sort_by.with_index{|_,i| b[i]} } }
  bench.report('zip')     { n.times { b.zip(a).sort.transpose } }
end
```

Here's the output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 1]]
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 1]]
Using 1000000 iterations:
              user     system      total        real
sort_by   2.370000   0.000000   2.370000 (  2.371345)
zip       2.730000   0.000000   2.730000 (  2.730663)
```

Comment: Thanks for the data man. And this is the performance for only array of 3 items.

Comment: Yes, only three, done a million times. It'd be all relative with variations on the iterations or the array sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Even though @steenslag gives a good solution, I would still not recommend using `zip` for its low performance, especially if the arrays are large because it generates an intermediate array.

The following code is more straight forward:

```
a = [[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]]
b = [5, 3, 4]
p a.sort_by.with_index{|_,i| b[i]}
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: Even I give a good solution? :)

Comment: @steenslag Even Ruby is not very good at performance, I would still try to minimize the performance issue. Your solution will iterate `a` and `b` once each, generate an intermediate array with size `a+b`, and then generates an intermediate hash for sorting. Mine iterates a once, then generates a sorting hash :)